# How to replicate MySQL database to Cloud SQL Database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have read that you can replicate a Cloud SQL database to MySQL. Instead, I want to replicate from a MySQL database (that the business uses to keep inventory) to Cloud SQL so it can have up-to-date inventory levels for use on a web site.

Is it possible to replicate MySQL to Cloud SQL. If so, how do I configure that?

Comment: If the DB isn't too big and only need to be replicated one way you could just dump it as a SQL statements and replace the cloud database. It should be easy to make an ETL type of job that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that is not yet possible in CloudSQL.

Comment: bummer. replication to Cloud SQL would be great to have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DBSync to do it, and working fine.

http://dbconvert.com/mysql.php

The Sync version do the service that you want.

It work well with App Engine and Cloud SQL. You must authorize external conections first.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question, but it might be worth noting that this seems now possible by [Configuring External Masters](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master).

The high level steps are:

- Create a dump of the data from the master and upload the file to a storage bucket
- Create a master instance in CloudSQL
- Setup a replica of that instance, using the external master IP, username and password. Also provide the dump file location
- Setup additional replicas if needed
- Voilà!